# Is it possible to save VM state without closing the VM window in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox

I'm using BTRFS and taking whole system snapshots for backup purposes.

In order not to loose the runtime state/data in the backups, I do `VBoxManage savestate "my running machine"` before taking the snapshot and then `VBoxManage start "my running machine"` after taking the snapshot.

Since the `savestate` command closes the VM windows, `start` command reopens the VM but brings its window in the front (naturally).

Is it possible to save the state of the VM without closing its window, so we could resume the operation without changing the window order (thus without disturbing the user's focus)?

## Further explanation

While the system snapshots are taken by `btrfs sub snap ...`, all data **on the disk** is backed up. This operation runs once an hour. However, RAM contents of running VMs can not be captured. If the primary disk of the laptop is crashed, the system is ready to boot from the secondary disk.

If the system is booted from the secondary disk and the VM is started, it will start as if the VM is forcefully closed (because no RAM content is captured).

If `savestate` was run before the snapshot operation and the primary disk fails, the VM will start where it is left when the system is booted from the secondary disk.

Comment: Virtual Machine Snapshots are not meant for backing up a VM.  Just back up the VM separately.

Comment: @John I added the "Further explanation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such an operation would be equivalent to creating a VM snapshot:

```
vboxmanage snapshot <vm> take "temp-backup-snapshot"
[backup]
vboxmanage snapshot <vm> delete "temp-backup-snapshot"
```

If taken while the VM is still running, the snapshot will include CPU/memory state as well (and restoring it would resume the VM).

Comment: There will be lots and lots of snapshots I guess. Should I need to merge them afterwards?

Comment: Just delete the VM snapshots immediately after creating the filesystem snapshot.

Comment: Oh, yes, you had already addressed that. Thank you!

Comment: Yesterday my pc crashed and I recovered 10 days of work. Thank you!